# discord.js BOT - ERROR Creating Channels with Permissions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm performing a bot that can help me to create many channels with specific permissions for a tournament. Channels name are "Team1-vs-Team2". In the server we have Roles defined with the same name as each team (i.e. members from "BarcelonaFC" has a role named "BarcelonaFC")

So, let's say that for this round BarcelonaFC faces RealMadrid, then the command executed will be:

```
  $stage
  BarcelonaFC-vs-RealMadrid
```

Then, the result should be the creation of a channel named "BarcelonaFC-vs-RealMadrid" with roles BarcelonaFC and RealMadrid assigned to it with specific permissions

This is my code (it's adjusted only to assign BarcelonaFC role with the HOME info) :

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
if (message.author.bot) return;
if (message.content.startsWith(process.env.PREFIX)) {
    const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
        .trim()
        .substring(process.env.PREFIX.length)
        .split(/\n+/);
    if (CMD_NAME === 'del') {
        message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => channel.delete());
        message.guild.channels.create('General', { type: 'text' });
        message.guild.channels.create('FRENTE XXXX', { type: 'category' });
    }
    if (CMD_NAME === 'stage') {
        if (args.length == 0) return message.reply('Please provide a stage number and teams');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < process.env.QTY_LLAVES; i++) {
            const [HOME, AWAY] = args[i].split('-vs-');
            let roleH = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === HOME);

            message.guild.channels.create(args[i], { 
                type: 'text',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                        id: roleH.id,
                        allow: permAllowed,
                        deny: permDenied,

                    },
                ],
            
            }).then((channel) => {
                const categoryId = message.guild.channels.cache.find(cat => cat.name === 'FRENTE XXXX');
                channel.setParent(categoryId);
                
            })
```

As a result, I have an error on following line within permissionsOverwrites:

```
     id: roleH.id,
```

Error obtained

```
   C:\Users\alexi\Desktop\Discord\OESTE-FWT\pikabot\src\pikabot.js:121
                        id: roleH.id,
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alexi\Desktop\Discord\OESTE-FWT\pikabot\src\pikabot.js:121:39)
```

I need help please to identify why is 'undefined' and why I got this error.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: After roleH assignment, I've run a console.log(roleH) and get this for the first iteration:
IMPORTANT NOTE: The role I've used here is called 'boca' (it's an latin team). Sorry to not used Barcelona or Real Madrid.

```
Role {
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
    members: GuildMemberManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    channels: GuildChannelManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    roles: RoleManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    presences: PresenceManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {}
    },
    voiceStates: VoiceStateManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    deleted: false,
    available: true,
    id: '836369921939210250',
    shardID: 0,
    name: "pilo's server",
    icon: null,
    splash: null,
    discoverySplash: null,
    region: 'brazil',
    memberCount: 3,
    large: false,
    features: [],
    applicationID: null,
    afkTimeout: 300,
    afkChannelID: null,
    systemChannelID: null,
    embedEnabled: undefined,
    premiumTier: 0,
    premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
    verificationLevel: 'NONE',
    explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
    mfaLevel: 0,
    joinedTimestamp: 1619656895701,
    defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
    systemChannelFlags: SystemChannelFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    maximumMembers: 100000,
    maximumPresences: null,
    approximateMemberCount: null,
    approximatePresenceCount: null,
    vanityURLCode: null,
    vanityURLUses: null,
    description: null,
    banner: null,
    rulesChannelID: null,
    publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
    preferredLocale: 'en-US',
    ownerID: '440862122201579520',
    emojis: GuildEmojiManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular *1]
    }
  },
  id: '840675247035383890',
  name: 'boca',
  color: 2123412,
  hoist: false,
  rawPosition: 5,
  permissions: Permissions { bitfield: 1983368913 },
  managed: false,
  mentionable: false,
  deleted: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bot can't find the given name role which is split from message provided please make sure you have role with the name that bot is looking for.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.
All roles are defined within the server and there is no difference between the name in the input and the role defined in Discord server.
Also, if I put a console.log(roleH) before entering in the create channel method, the console shows me all the role definition

Comment: Can I get a type or o log of roleH

Comment: Thank you again! Sorry for the delay, I'm new and getting used with notifications. I've edited the post with the console.log(roleH). Let me know for anything.